# Event simulation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

How can I simulate events like click, mousedown, mouseout and etc. in JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: Look at the jQuery trigger event - http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the trigger method

```
$(element).trigger('click');
```

More information: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

Events can be attached to each element in a HTML page. Check out the following link to understand events better.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp

Comment: That is all about attaching event handlers, not simulating events — the opposite of what was asked for. (Also, it is best to avoid W3Schools, they have [many problems](http://w3fools.com/)).